# How to hide specific rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a df with books titles, authors etc. I want to hide some specific rows where the book_category = 'biography'.

The thing is that I just want to hide these rows - don't remove them from entire df as I can't change the shape of this df. I need to hide them only visually. I was trying with loc selection, but unfortunately this changed the shape of my df. Do you know the method how to do this operation?

Answer (score 2):

You could save the rows you want in another temporary dataframe and display this one:

```
df2 = df[df['book_category'] != 'biography']
```

Comment: Yes, but the thing is that for this specific case I really can't change the shape of any df. I need to only filter these rows without changing the shape. I was thinking about using df.styler, but as I see there is no option for row selection